# jQuery Validate - form disappears on success

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple form that validates using jQuery Validate, and I'm running into an issue I've never seen before. I have a form wrapped in a container that validates using a validation summary, and when you enter some information in one of the fields that validates successfully and then tab off, the entire content of the container disappears.  I think it has to do with the wrapper property matching the container that the form is in.  You can see this behavior in the following code snippet/jsFiddles:

```
$('#form1').validate({
        wrapper: 'p',
        errorContainer: '#jserror',
        errorClass: 'jserror',
        errorLabelContainer: '#ValidationErrors',
        highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            $(element).addClass('errorfields');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            $(element).removeClass('errorFields');
        },
        rules : {},
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Name is required"
            },
            postSlug: {
                postSlug: "Can only contain numbers, letters, dashes and underscores",
                required: "Post slug is required"
            }
        }
    });// end validate
```

Form and title are wrapped in ul/li, and that content completely disappears when setting wrapper : 'li'
http://jsfiddle.net/tjans/cqXXu/41/

Form and title are wrapped in div, and that content completely disappears when setting wrapper : 'div'
http://jsfiddle.net/tjans/cqXXu/44/

Form and title are wrapped in div, wrapper is set to 'p', everything works fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/tjans/cqXXu/45/

Is this a bug, or is there a work-around/better syntax for doing this?

Comment: "disappears when setting wrapper" - ONLY true on the required - enter an invalid email address first to see what I mean

Comment: Correct, only on the required fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for you is that the plugin is also setting `display:none` on the parent of your `errorLabelContainer`.

Try this way instead...

**HTML**:

```
<div id="ValidationErrors" class="messageContainer validation" style="display:none;">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

**Validation option**:

```
errorLabelContainer: '#ValidationErrors ul',
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/uWVZ9/**

---

This one has nothing to do with your problem, but I'd also remove the empty `rules: {}` ... that's never a good idea and it's totally superfluous since your rules are already defined inline with the HTML.

Comment: Damn skippy, that was it.  I looked at some old examples of this in my other code that worked and I always had a div around the validation errors, so I never ran into this before now. Thanks for the assistance...

Comment: You could also simply just wrap the ValidationErrors container in a div and not change anything else and it would accomplish the same effect.